# What is the difference between response.sendError() and throwing an exception using the throw keyword?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

What is the difference between the two approaches below?

***Case 1:***

```
    public void onFail(HttpServletResponse response, org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException exception)
         response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
```

In this case I get this output and I *can* control the HTTP status code:

```
    {
      "timestamp": 1458974564628,
      "status": 401,
      "error": "Unauthorized",
      "message": "Authentication Failed: null",
      "path": "/api/myservice1"
    }
```

***Case 2:***

```
    public void onFail(){
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token");
    }
```

In this case I get this output and I *can't* control the HTTP status code,

```
    {
      "timestamp": 1458974259995,
      "status": 403,
      "error": "Forbidden",
      "exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
      "message": "Access Denied",
      "path": "/api/myservice1"
    }
```

In case 2, where and how is the 403 status mapped to a `BadCredentialsException`? How can I override it and send a 401 response instead of a 403 response?

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Security.

Comment: One is sending error result over the network without significantly stopping anything. The other is throwing the exception. You need to understand concept of throw to be able to understand the difference.

Comment: With `HttpServletResponse#sendError` you specifically set the HTTP status code, and also an optional message that client will receive. When throwing an exception, if there is no handler to catch the exception, servlet container will send 500 status message to the client. But when you're using a framework like Spring you've the ability to define different exception handlers to catch the thrown exception(in your case `BadCredentialsException`) and customize the response sent to the client.

Comment: Please capitalize, punctuate, spell-check, and grammaticise your title and your question,

Comment: Which framework and container do you use?

Comment: @Henry I update my question. I use spring boot with spring security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you throw an excpetion it depends on how your application/framework react on the BadCredentialsException. If no one will catch it you will get a HTTP Response-Code 500. 
In your first case  the client get's a 'proper' response (HTTP 401). But that is only the clients view.

From the applications point of view I would strongly recommend the first approach. You know what is going on and you have all the information to react on this scenario. So there is no reason why to throw an exception and let "someone else" descide what to do.

You might have a look at this article which is about using exceptions for control-flow: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl. That is not exactly your problem but at least some aspects might be interesting to read. If you are generaly unsure about when to throw an exception and when not it might help you to have a look at the documentation from oracle which is quite good at this point: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html.

My rule of thumb would be: If you can handle a certain scenario localy do it. If you miss some information or can't handle the error localy: throw an exception.

Comment: I think you had a typo in your answer where, when you say my second case, you meant the first case right? I have edit my question. Btw in my second case, where and how is this status": 403 is mapped to BadCredentialsException. I mean can we override it and send 401 instead of 403

Comment: You're right thanks for pointing that out. I modified my answer.

Comment: thanks i think you still have a typo in first paragraph. btw do u hav any answer for my question in comment?

Comment: @Harshana: I'm not sure where the BadCredentialsException is mapped to a 403. Which framework are you using? Spring?